# Parse.com need to create a zip file on server side

Tags: parse-platform

Suppose I need to read some data and images from Parse.com objects on server side, zip them up and send them to the browser. How can I do that in my cloud code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not possible:

> No, I talked to parse support team and at that time there were no
>   option to do that. I ended downloading everything to my server and zip
>   it there.
>   - Alberto 11 months ago

https://www.parse.com/questions/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-zip-files-with-cloud-code

If you have an account with them, shouldn't you contact them for support with their API?

Comment: Maybe some 3rd party modules?